# purge old data(logstash) from Redis

Tags: redis, logstash

I have simple configuration:
logstash send logs to redis,  logstash read from redis and send data into elastic search

```
redis {
 host => 'XXX'
 data_type => 'list'
 key => 'logstash:redis'
 batch => true
 batch_events => 100
 }
```

my question is: how to delete already indexed data from the redis server.

Comment: What do you mean? Logstash deletes messages from the Redis broker as they're being retrieved.

Comment: Like @MagnusBäck suggested, the events which are already being pulled form redis, and parsed by logstash will be deleted by logstash upon retrieval and successful processing. But for your satisfaction, you can still check the size of `dump.rdb` which should be close to 4K